# How can I present a Date & Time picker in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a form field for a datetime property that allows the user to use a calendar for picking the date and also have something to choose the time graphically.

I've managed to get the jQuery UI DatePicker working for the date, but I have not way of presenting the time.

Is there a single component that does both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't seen for both. But for time, [this one](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/) looks really good.

Comment: That is awesome. I really like it. It's giving some quirky CSS problems in my existing project, but I think I can make it work.